# How to register a var in either one or another task

Tags: ansible

This task collection doesn't work as I hoped it would:

```
- name: Find out whether syslog-ng is installed (yum)
  tags: syslog_forwarding
  command: yum -q list installed syslog-ng
  register: syslog_ng_check
  failed_when: False
  changed_when: False
  when: ansible_pkg_mgr == 'yum'

- name: Find out whether syslog-ng is installed (apt)
  tags: syslog_forwarding
  command: dpkg -s syslog-ng
  register: syslog_ng_check
  failed_when: False
  changed_when: False
  when: ansible_pkg_mgr == 'apt'

- name: Configure syslog-ng to forward all logs to syslog servers (apt)
  tags: syslog_forwarding
  template:
    src: syslog_ng_forward_all.conf.j2
    dest: /etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/syslog_forward.conf
  notify: restart syslog_ng
  when: syslog_ng_check is defined and syslog_ng_check.rc == 0

- name: Configure syslog-ng to forward all logs to syslog servers (yum)
  tags: syslog_forwarding
  template:
    src: syslog_ng_forward_all.conf.j2
    dest: /etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/syslog_forward.conf
  notify: restart syslog_ng
  when: syslog_ng_check is defined and syslog_ng_check.rc == 0
```

I wanted to first find out whether `syslog-ng` was installed on the system (the system might either be a `CentOS` or a `Debian/Ubuntu`), and then act accordingly (place a config file) when so, and keep the task to place the config file distribution independent. 
What I have found out is that if the first task actually returns 0 and sets `syslog-ng-check.rc` to 0, then the second task makes it be undefined again (or at least, empty), even though the task is skipped (as no system can be using `yum` and `apt` at the same time, at least not mine).

Of course, I could register different variables for each `yum` and `apt` checks, but then I would need more logic in my when: clause which I wanted to avoid.

Any good ideas on this one?

Answer (score 1):

There are only workarounds. Skipped tasks will always overwrite registered variable.

One possible way:

```
- name: Find out whether syslog-ng is installed (yum)
  tags: syslog_forwarding
  command: yum -q list installed syslog-ng
  register: syslog_ng_check
  failed_when: False
  changed_when: False
  when: ansible_pkg_mgr == 'yum'

- set_fact:
    syslog_ng_flag: True
  when: syslog_ng_check.rc == 0

- name: Find out whether syslog-ng is installed (apt)
  tags: syslog_forwarding
  command: dpkg -s syslog-ng
  register: syslog_ng_check
  failed_when: False
  changed_when: False
  when: ansible_pkg_mgr == 'apt'

- set_fact:
    syslog_ng_flag: True
  when: syslog_ng_check.rc == 0

- name: Configure syslog-ng to forward all logs to syslog servers (apt)
  tags: syslog_forwarding
  template:
    src: syslog_ng_forward_all.conf.j2
    dest: /etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/syslog_forward.conf
  notify: restart syslog_ng
  when: syslog_ng_flag | default(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just slightly reorder your tasks to make your "configure" task immediately follow the test  ("find out..") as a pair,  i.e.:

```
- name: Find out whether syslog-ng is installed (yum)
- name: Configure syslog-ng to forward all logs to syslog servers (yum)
- name: Find out whether syslog-ng is installed (yum)
- name: Configure syslog-ng to forward all logs to syslog servers (apt)
```

That way even if the other test resets syslog_ng_check you don't care because the you've already used it.

Putting the find/configure pair for each of the two pkg managers in a block guarded by `when: ansible_pkg_mgr == ...` would be another way, and would make it more obvious that the ordering/grouping was important.