# apt-get not registering variable in ansible

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, apt-get

Whenever I try to install a package like this (as an example) on ubuntu;

```
- name: Install gcc
  apt:
    name: gcc
    state: present
    allow_unauthenticated: yes
  register: aptout
```

Regardless of whether gcc is not installed, I get this for aptout;

```
- debug:
    msg: "Status is {{ aptout }}"
```

.

```
"msg": "Status is {'skipped': True, 'changed': False, 'skip_reason': u'Conditional check failed'}"
```

I wanted to register this check so that I can skip tasks if the package is already installed using `not aptout.changed` and `aptout.changed` but it seems to not be registering the variable properly.

This works fine on redhat/centos, but just can't figure out the issue with Ubuntu.

Comment: Please post the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you are confused what you should do - then start with the code from this question (not the one you are currently running) and add things until you get the error you posted. When you get that - post the code, full (and not the full one you are currently running, but the minimal code you needed to replicate the problem).

Comment: Try [this](http://chaosmail.github.io/programming/2015/03/04/install-deb-packages-in-ansible/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything works as expected.

```
apt_out = { 'skipped': True,
            'changed': False,
            'skip_reason': u'Conditional check failed'}
```

Ansible says that your task has not been run: `skipped: true`, because of false condition (why didn't you include it in the example?).

So it can't guess is `gcc` installed or not because it didn't event start this task.

Comment: Are you using ansible 2.1 or 2.2 (I'm using 2.1)? The problem is it keeps saying that regardless of whether gcc is installed or not. It shouldn't show it as skipped if is not originally on the server.

Comment: @user1165419 you use `when` statement, which is evaluated to false during your playbook run – that is why your task is skipped. Remove `when` statement and task will always run giving your a `changed` value.

Comment: You're right. I need to post the full playbook, I think what's happening is that I'm trying to install gcc for both ubuntu and centos, using the same variables. So when I want to install it for ubuntu, it installs it (registers the variable as 'changed'), then skips centos (registers the same variable as 'skipped') which is what we're seeing. Mhm, need to find a way for it avoid registering the variable when the task is skipped.

Comment: Yes, posting full context is always a good idea. You may want to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41335880/2795592). Or if you have many tasks for either platforms, read about [dynamic includes](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#dynamic-versus-static-includes) and consider something like `include: "prepare_{{ ansible_os_family | lower }}.yml"`.