# Ansible, check file exists in the http path before get_url/win_get_url

Tags: ansible

I must be missing something but suppose, I would like download some file from http:// location. It fails if file is missing, I would like to exit the playbook run if the file is missing and not to fail.
Example like that, doesn't work on http located files

```
- stat: path=/usr/local/foo
  register: foo_var
- meta: end_play
  when: foo_var.stat.exists
```

Comment: "*It fails if file is missing*" - missing where? At the specified URL? Besides, you are supposed to include the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the error message - either is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although your question lacks some required info, I guess you look for something like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    # check url with HEAD request
    - uri:
        url: http://localhost:8000/key.pub
        method: HEAD
      register: uri_test
      # fail with error if status is unexpected
      failed_when: uri_test.status is undefined or uri_test.status <= 0
    # gracefully end play if http code is fatal
    - meta: end_play
      when: uri_test.status > 400
    # else download
    - get_url:
        url: http://localhost:8000/key.pub
        dest: /tmp/key.pub
```

You can actually skip `uri` test and use only `get_url` with `ignore_errors: yes` or carefully crafted `failed_when` statement.

Comment: Thanks, now the problem that I use one playbook for linux and windows hosts. Is there a way to use this code in both OSs?
I don't want to do cases "when" and do same code twice. Once uri and then win_uri

Comment: To use registered variable with same name from different calls, you have to jump through some hoops (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41335880/2795592)).

Answer (score 0):

The uri module and many other modules have different names on windows

It is unlikely that the same task will work on both. The code logic however may well work.

I ended up using a power-shell solution on windows inside a shell task

```yaml
- name: "Check if the model already exists on artifactory!"
  win_shell: |
    $URI = New-Object System.Uri("{{ artifactory_model_path }}.zip")
    $user = "{{ ci_user }}"
    $pass = "{{ artifactory_header_ci_user }}"
    $pair = "$($user):$($pass)"
    $encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
    $basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"
    $Headers = @{
      Authorization = $basicAuthValue
    }
    (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri  $URI -Headers $Headers -UseBasicParsing -DisableKeepAlive -Method head).StatusCode
  register: models_return_code
  ignore_errors: true
```

you can however use something like this to load different code depending on the OS in the same play

```yaml
- name: Include system-specific variables or tasks
  include_tasks: "{{ ansible_os_family | lower }}.yml"
```

Comment: But for windows you can use `win_uri`: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_uri_module.html